# How do I *use* a custom function in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have some vba code in excel as follows:

```
Public Sub simulatedCall()
    Debug.Print "The revised rate is: "; dderiveTodaysRate(1)
End Sub


Public Function dderiveTodaysRate(ATRItemID As Integer) As Variant

    revisedConstructionCost = 175.352 * ATRItemID
    revisedBitumenCost = 98.451 * ATRItemID

    dderiveTodaysRate = Round(revisedConstructionCost + revisedBitumenCost, 2)

End Function
```

Now, in excel, I have a table, and in one of the columns, I have put the following formula:

```
= dderiveTodaysRate([@ID])
```

But I cannot get it to work. All I'm getting is `#VALUE!`

If I put the formula in a  "normal" cell, then it works

[image: |2]

So, do custom formulas not work in Tables?

Comment: What are `revisedConstructionCost` and `revisedBitumenCost`? Please create a [reprex].

Comment: Or rather, what are you doing in those `...`.

Comment: I can't share all information, so I've created a sample and updated my question.

Comment: It's best to not assume that you are using the formula incorrectly. You are probably using it correctly, but it is not written correctly for the data in your table. If you take that "1,2,3,4" example which works, and turn it into a table, does it still work?

Comment: It works for me, I'd suggest you don't have your custom function in a module ... https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f

Comment: You've also defined your function as `dderiveTodaysRate` and your fomula has `deriveTodaysRate` so you have a disconnect anyway.

Comment: @Kevin, yes turn the data into a table, it carries on working.

Comment: @Skin, yep, fixed that. options are Module or class module, I'm using Module. Does it maybe have to be in it's own module?

Comment: It should be in a module, not necessarily it's own.  Just in a module.  So it's working now?

Comment: @Skin If it wasn't in a module, the error would have been `#NAME!`, not `#VALUE!`. `#VALUE!` means the function is found and invoked.

Comment: @Maxcot What kind of values are found in your `ID` column?

Comment: @GSerg ahhhh true ...!  Must be a numeracy thing.

Comment: @Maxcot so maybe the question is answered - yes you are using the function correctly, yes you can use it in a table. The example you've given also works without error. Everything you have shared here works. The only thing that doesn't work is the information you haven't shared. Difficult to help fix it if you can't share it.

Comment: My "ID" column is just an integer from 1 to 9000. There are 9000 rows. I think I'm going to try iterate through the ID values in a script, and see if ALL the IDs work in the function.  Maybe there's something I'm not seeing.

Comment: Is your posted code for the UDF the *exact* code you're actually using?  It's important in this context.

Comment: I've decided to abandon this approach. I have concluded that having a piece of script called on demand to update the table is better than trying a complex custom function in the table that ideally would be automatically recalculating all the time.